# Can I - V support the melodic motion ^3 ^5?

Tags: voice-leading

The outer voices would move into a P8 by leap which is supposed to be hidden octaves and not good. Is this indeed a bad progression and would another harmony be better here? I normally would just stay on I here but if I have a weak beat ^3 followed by a strong beat ^5 I wont be able to use the same chord.

Comment: The V chord does not contain the ^3 scale degree; you need V13 instead - do you mean that both ^3 and ^5 are for the I chord instead?

Comment: @Dekkadeci is exactly right. The question doesn't make sense as asked. Maybe add a picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: oops, had the chords the wrong way around, sorry guys

Comment: You can do anything you want if you like the sound of it. Are you trying to make sure what you’re doing matches a certain style or genre? If so then you’ll have to tell us what that style or genre is.

Comment: yeah yeah, I have heard this one before and I did what sounded good for 10 years before picking up a harmony book, what sounded good then doesnt sound so good now. In 4 part harmony hidden octaves are discouraged... having said that, can there be any doubt about the context of my question?

Comment: ^3 backed by I into ^5 backed by V is the beginning of "O Canada", Canada's national anthem. I therefore doubt that this is a "bad progression", but maybe the analysts will indeed spit at Calixa Lavallée's questionable choice of composition methods and find the piece hard to assign to SATB voices.

Comment: @Dekkadeci, I think the specific harmonization of _O Canada_ matters. I see a hymnal that gives `I V6` rather than the OP's `I V` - root position - then direct octaves become a concern.

Comment: @armani, re: "...what sounded good then doesn't sound so good now..." are you trying to get the stylistic sound of the 18th century? Composers like Handel, Mozart, Vivaldi, etc.

Comment: not at all, I was trying to say that learning tonal harmony has made the world of difference to my perception of music and revisitng my old compositions I find them to be amateurish. This is to say that what sounds good changes as your ear develops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of the outer voices especially in terms of two part writing, then the bare octave also becomes a bit of a concern. It sounds sort of "hollow."

The way out of that is a preference for thirds/sixths: `^3 ^5` harmonized with `I V6`. I think this would be the "standard" two part harmony for `^3 ^5` and tonic/dominant harmony.

Another way to think of the implied harmony of `^3 ^5` is simply an arpeggiation of `I`, and so no chord change.

I supposed you could mitigate the direct octaves concern by moving the base in contrary motion.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is a perfect answer. Great!

Comment: Base or bass? Not sure if that’s a typo…

Comment: I do think of the outer voices in two part writing as is taught in my textbook and I totally get why they first teach species counterpoint before going into 4 part writing. The rules might be old and annoying at times but they do ensure good sounding harmonic progressions.